# Titanium Appcelerator Social logins

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

Without using plugins like social.js, birdhouse.js or codebird.js.. Is it possible to create social logins, tweets and so on using authentication provider api docs.. Because javascript approach for google login is same for all web projects so if we do it, it has to work in ios and also android. Many solutions for social sharing in Appcelerator are platform based, then what is the meaning in cross-platform. If I understood anything wrong, please do suggest me right path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of the libraries you mentioned use the vendor specific APIs, so I don't really understand question

Comment: Hi Aaron, the problem cant we go by the way mentioned in google api docs for loging and sharing posts into google plus and for facebook and twitter as well. Why we should a plugin like social.js. I cant understand, Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a service like Google+, you can use their [http api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/). In Titanium, you can use the [http client](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) to send requests and get responses. Since its from Titanium api, it should be cross-platforms.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: +1 ... Yes exactly.. But how to authorize my app and provide return URL and post a stream in google plus like that and all ...

Comment: You can use a webview to implement the login screen and button as you would do with a standard webpage, and get the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this github library to authorize:

https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium